# Improve If else statement coding

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a drop down list contain "Add" and "Subtract".  When user select either one, it will call a function Calculate()

```
private int Calculate(string sAction)
{
   int iTotal = 0;
   if(sAction == "Add")
   {
       iTotal = X + Y;
   }
   else if(sAction == "Subtract")
   {
       iTotal = X-Y;
   }       
   return iTotal;
}
```

I do not wish to hard coded it to compare the action.  It seem like not fulfill Open Closed Principle.  If I change the text in the drop down list, I need to change the function as well.  May I know how I can improve this code?

Comment: I think you should post this into https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You could use an enum to populate the dropdown and check the values of the enum. Also, you can change the `if...else if` construct to a `switch`. That will make it a little less code once you add more actions.

Comment: Consider a `Dictionary<string, Func>` and use it for populating the dropdown list.

Comment: I think your code is totally fine, why do you want to change it? It is easy to read and covers all cases.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Seems [you've just posted on CR](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/177586/1996).

Answer (score 2):

Be sure when you ever have a code that it has the chain of **if else** there should be an improvement so here my suggestion :

you can use something like this :

first Add a class for manage your actions :

```
 public class ActionManager : Dictionary<string, Func<int, int, int>>
    {
        public ActionManager()
        {
            this.Add("action", (x, y) => x + y);
            this.Add("Subtract", (x, y) => x - y);
        }

    }
```

Then you can use that class like this :

```
public class DoStuff
{
    private int Calculate(string sAction)
    {
        var actionManager = new ActionManager();
        var a = 1;
        var b = 2;
        //var actionResult= actionManager[this should come from your drop down].Invoke(a, b);
        var actionResult= actionManager[sAction].Invoke(a, b);


        //you can even Register New Action Like this :
        actionManager.Add("Multiply",(x,y)=>x*y);

        //then you can use it somewhere else:
        var multiplyResult =  actionManager["Multiply"].Invoke(a, b);
        return actionResult;
    }
}
```

so every time your action has change you just need to add the new action in your ActionManager. with this approach there is no need for that if else statement.

By the way, you can even use interface and DI to loose coupling the ActionManager.

Comment: I like this solution with dictionaries of delegates, nice one

Answer (score 1):

By using Enum you can achieve this without changing the hardcode value each time when the combo box item text changed.
The below example shows how to populate combo box and to retrieve the value from combo box using enum

Enum  Declaration

```
public enum Operation { Add= 0, Subtract= 1 };
```

Populate the combo box

```
cbOperation.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Operation ));
```

Perform operation based on selected item

```
Enum.TryParse(cbOperation.SelectedValue.ToString(), out Operation selectedOperation);
        switch (selectedOperation)
        {
            case Operation.Add:
                Console.WriteLine("Add operation selected");
                break;
            case Operation.Subtract:
                Console.WriteLine("Subtract operation selected");
                break;
        }
```

By doing this you don't need to change the combo box item text each time. You just change the enum value it automatically reflected in combo box.

Comment: Hi @Clinton Prakash, if I change the Add to Add_1 in Enum; I need change Add case to Operation.Add_1?

Comment: Hi @Derick Loo, Yes you need to change that too.